# RavenDB keeps getting 503 Service Unavailable error

Tags: c#, ravendb

I was using RavenDB for 3 days and it works normally and perfect. Until yesterday, suddenly it always return an error which is:

> {StatusCode: 503, ReasonPhrase: 'Service Unavailable', Version: 1.1,
>   Content: , Headers:{}} System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage

And the Raven Studio also shows 503 Service Unavailable. I install RavenDB in **IIS**. I manage to clear the port using this command:

```
netsh http delete urlacl http://*:8080/
```

And I can open the Raven Studio back. Once I run my project back, it shows the 503 error again and Raven Studio also shows 503 Service Unavailable again.

So, I *uninstall* and *reinstall* RavenDB using **Windows Service** one. And shows the same error, except the Raven Studio did not effected anymore.

When I debug the code, the error comes from the **session.SaveChanges()** method. I even try creating a simple object to be saved and still return the same **error 503** message. Here is what is shows in the Console:

```
Trying to grant rights for http.sys
runas netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/ user="SURFPRO4\Riza"
Failed to grant rights for listening to http, exit codes: (0 and 0)
```

So, I suspect because of the last message:

> **Failed** to grant rights for listening to http, exit codes: (0 and 0)

What I don't understand is, it was okay for 3 days as I did not change or update any codes related within.

## Adding Codes

```
NonAdminHttp.EnsureCanListenToWhenInNonAdminContext(8080);
Store = new DocumentStore
{
    Url = "http://localhost:8080",
    DefaultDatabase = "RizaDB"
};
Store.Initialize();
```

and for saving:

```
using (var session = Store.OpenSession())
{
    session.Store(@event);
    session.SaveChanges(); // <--- The error trips here
}
```

#### Fiddler

[image]

I change the port to 32000 and it works. However, when I ran the project, it dumps this every time wants to save the data.

```
Trying to revoke rights for http.sys
runas netsh http delete urlacl url=http://+:32000/
Trying to grant rights for http.sys
runas netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:32000/ user="SURFPRO4\Riza"
Failed to grant rights for listening to http, exit codes: (0 and 0)
Trying to revoke rights for http.sys
runas netsh http delete urlacl url=http://+:32000/
Trying to grant rights for http.sys
runas netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:32000/ user="SURFPRO4\Riza"
Failed to grant rights for listening to http, exit codes: (0 and 0)
```

Can anyone help me with this issue. Many thanks.

Comment: What is the _actual_ reason for the 503 error? If you look in Fiddler, it should give you additional details. It has nothing to do with IIS / Service, etc.

Comment: *I did not change or update any codes related within.* - are you absolutely sure? Were there other changes you weren't aware of?

Comment: @tomredfern I'm sure no code changes. However, I did install SQL Server 2016 and SSMS. Is there any relation with this, maybe?

Comment: I add the codes in the question.

Comment: The netshell add access control command requires local administration rights. Does the raven service have these permissions? If not then can you run the command manually to open up the port to raven to listen to?

Comment: @AyendeRahien the error I get is from the view detail properties. There is no exception or inner exception message.

Comment: @tomredfern Yes, all my dev environment is "Run as Administrator". And I even did enable the full control in the RavenDB folder security tab for my login account.

Comment: 503 always has some sort of reason inside it. At worst, you'll be able to see the RavenDB headers. Please post the fiddler output.

Comment: @AyendeRahien I change the port to 32000 and it works. However, it dumps the "trying to grant rights for http.sys" several times when saving. I added the Fiddler and the console output in the question.

Comment: That is fine when you are starting.